# What actions can be taken as a free action?

Tags: star-wars-x-wing

I just got my first model for X-Wing Minis (an E-Wing) and received a card in the box called "Advanced Sensors". It's a 3-point card granting "**...1 free action...**" "**Immediately before you reveal your maneuver,...**". My question is **What can I do as a Free Action using this card?** All I can find in the rule book is that it is "something specified in a card or a game type" and nothing else.

Comment: Have you got a core set of some sort? You need one of those to play the game. The extra ships are just expansions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Free actions are actions that are specified on **the ship's action bar**, **other cards** or **special mission rules**. You can normally only perform actions during the Perform Action step of the Activation phase.

**Advanced Sensors** allows you to perform any one of these free actions outside of the regular step at the cost of skipping that step.

From the X-Wing Rules [reference](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/40/b4/40b44d5f-7a06-406c-ae6e-183c5297e796/swx36_rulesreference.pdf) (pg 12)

> A free action is an action granted to a ship through a card ability or other effect. It does not count as the one standard action that a ship performs during the “Perform Action” step.
>
> • A stressed ship cannot perform free actions.
>
> • A ship can perform free actions even if it skipped its “Perform Action” step due to overlapping an asteroid obstacle or another game effect.
>
> • If a ship is specifically granted a free barrel roll action or a free boost action and cannot complete the action in the desired direction, it may choose a different direction. It cannot choose to perform a different action.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the page, I guess I didn't read it closely enough the first time...